# Rails - Building a Wizard . Where to start, where to store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm interested in building a wizard for my web app that users use when they first login in that has 3 simple steps:

- Upload profile photo
- Profile Info
- Find Friends

That kind of thing. so my question is how do I do this with Rails?

The GettingStarted will essentially have the 3 views above. With Next/Back/Skip buttons. Where do I submit? How do I track the current view and decide how to show the next view?

I realize this is a bigger/broader question and appreciate any high level thinking you can share on how to smartly handle this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some considerations must be made before ultimately deciding on a solution. For instance, must this wizard be completed before moving on to the actual application, or is it something that can be entirely bypassed by (for example) signing in from a different computer?

Assuming it's ok to bypass it, I would create a namespace (for instance, getting_started) with three nested resources: photo, profile, and friends. There is really no need to track which step a user is on, as you can simply forward from one step to the next after submission, and add back and skip buttons where necessary.

The most important point, though, is to namespace this wizard and avoid polluting the "normal" controllers for these resources with wizard-specific actions. In this way, things stay REST-ful and organized.

Routes might look something like:

```
namespace :getting_started do
  resource :photo, :only => [:edit, :update]
  resource :profile, :only => [:edit, :update]
  resources :friends, :only => [:index, :create]
end
```

Comment: @Brian, it can be something that can be bypassed

Comment: I think I'm getting the routes part but what about the controller and views?

Comment: Hmm the views will be different. Example, The view for uploading your profile pic are different in getting started versus normally in the site by profile edit?

Comment: does getting_started need to be deinfed in the routes. I'm getting an error "ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Gettingstarted" ... fyi I changed it from getting_started to gettingstarted.

Comment: I added a getting_started controller. Routes updated to:  resources :getting_started  
  namespace :getting_started do
    resource :users, :only => [:edit, :update]
  end
 .... Now when I try: "/getting_started/users/edit" I get the error : "Unknown action
The action 'edit' could not be found for GettingStartedController"

Comment: You don't need a GettingStartedController. You just need to place the controllers inside a directory within app/controllers. For instance, the PhotosController would be at app/controllers/gettingstarted/photos_controller.rb. Associated views will need to be namespaced similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this railscasts. I imagine it will be a good starting point for you.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: This is really good. Problem is my Getting Started wizard isn't associated to a model the way the railscast is to order. My getting started relates to multiple products.. So where do I handle that in the model?

Comment: I think this approach is good when the form is truly multi-step, but this wizard sounds like it could be abandoned at any step and all previously-entered info should be retained.